# python positive and negative number list possibilities

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a function in Python that takes a list of integers as input and returns a greater list containing all positive and negative possibilities of those numbers.

Pretend  '+'  is a positive number and  '-'  is a negative number

The output should match up with:

```
foo([-4])
>>> [ [4], [-4] ]

foo([+, +])
>>> [ [+,+], [+,-], [-,+], [-,-] ]

foo([-, +])
>>> [ [+,+], [+,-], [-,+], [-,-] ]

foo([-1, 3])
>>> [ [1,3], [1,-3], [-1,3], [-1,-3] ]

foo( [+,-,+] )
>>> [ [-,-,-],[+,-,-],[-,+,-],[-,-,+],[+,+,-],[+,-,+],[-,+,+],[+,+,+] ]
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think he's using + and - as an informal stand in for actual positive and negative numbers.

Comment: Is the order of the output list important?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For just numbers, you can use `itertools.product` to create all combos, after generating a list with both positive and negative numbers:

```
from itertools import product

def foo(nums):
    return list(product(*((x, -x) for x in nums)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> foo([-4])
[(4,), (-4,)]
>>> foo([-1, 3])
[(1, 3), (1, -3), (-1, 3), (-1, -3)]
>>> foo([1, 3])
[(1, 3), (1, -3), (-1, 3), (-1, -3)]
>>> foo([1, -3, 4])
[(1, 3, 4), (1, 3, -4), (1, -3, 4), (1, -3, -4), (-1, 3, 4), (-1, 3, -4), (-1, -3, 4), (-1, -3, -4)]
```

Comment: Why make them positive, then negative? Why not `opposite = [-x for x in nums]` and `zip(nums, opposite)`

Comment: @GP89: already updated; no need to `zip` either by generating the tuples directly.

Comment: As a side note, if you don't actually need a list for the output, just something you can iterate over once, leave off the `list(…)` bit.

Answer (score 6):

```
list(itertools.product(*([x, -x] for x in input)))
```

You want every possible way to pick either a number or its negative, for each number in the input. That's the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of `{x[i], -x[i]}` for each `x[i]` in the input. [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) can do that for you, and then `list` makes a list of all the output.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Whoops. Input unpacked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itetools.product`, find the cartesian product of `[1, -1]` depending on the length of the input list and then multiple them with the items in the input list.

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> from itertools import product
def solve(lis):
    for prod in product([-1, 1], repeat=len(lis)):
        yield [mul(*x) for x in  zip(prod, lis)]
...         
>>> list(solve([-4]))
[[4], [-4]]
>>> list(solve([-1, 3]))
[[1, -3], [1, 3], [-1, -3], [-1, 3]]
```