# Pythonic way to calculate pair wise dot product inside a list

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list that consists of all combinations of tuples that each elements can only be -1 or 1. The list can be generated as:

```
N=2
list0 = [p for p in itertools.product([-1, 1], repeat=N)]
```

For example, if the tuple has `N=2` elements:

> list0 = [(-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]

Thus the total number of tuples is `2^2=4`.

If the tuple has `N=3` elements:

> list0 = [(-1, -1, -1), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, 1),
>    (1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, 1, 1)]

Here is my concern:

Now I would like to get all the results of dot products between any pair of tuples in the list(including ones a tuple with itself). So for `N=2` there will be `6(pairs) + 4(itself) = 10 combinations;` for `N=3` there will be `28(pairs) + 8(itself) = 36 combinations.`

For small `N` I can do something like:

```
for x in list0:
    for y in list0:
        print(np.dot(x,y))
```

However, assuming I already have list0, what is the optimal way to calculate all the possibilities of dot products, if N is large, like ~50?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python positive and negative number list possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156963/python-positive-and-negative-number-list-possibilities)

Comment: @Bazingaa No, that question is about how to generate the list. Mine is how to calculate all the dot products efficiently

Comment: @James Indeed, the main difference from simply getting all combinations and calling `np.dot` is that for half  of the pairs the result will be zero.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `np.dot` itself:

```
import numpy as np

list0 = [(-1, -1, -1), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, 1), (1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, 1, 1)]

# approach using np.dot
a = np.array(list0)
result = np.dot(a, a.T)

# brute force approach
brute = []
for x in list0:
    brute.append([np.dot(x, y) for y in list0])
brute = np.array(brute)

print((brute == result).all())
```

**Output**

```
True
```

What you are asking is the matrix multiplication of `a` with itself, from the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

> if both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication,

Note that the most *pythonic* solutio is to use the operator `@`:

```
import numpy as np

list0 = [(-1, -1, -1), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, 1), (1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, 1, 1)]

# approach using np.dot
a = np.array(list0)
result = a @ a.T

# brute force approach
brute = []
for x in list0:
    brute.append([np.dot(x, y) for y in list0])
brute = np.array(brute)

print((brute == result).all())
```

**Output**

```
True
```

**Note:** The code was run in Python 3.5

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. However, I think this is still brutal force. How is it different from two for loops?

Comment: @James the dot function is implemented in optimized C/C++, while the two `for` loops are implemented in Python. Also if you want to get all the dot products you I believe you have to compute all of them.

Comment: I think the range of the final result is fixed in [-N, N]. So probably we can build a hash table/array to store the counts of all the results, just like a histogram.

Comment: So you want the possible values or the actual values?

Comment: I want actual values. Possible values are definitely within [-N, N]. For actual values, we just need to count how many times one specific result appear, for all possible results.

Comment: I not sure if I'm following, still you have to compute all pairs of dot products and then count how many times a specific result appears. Using a hash table will only improve the counting.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit off track. Yes, I want to compute all pairs of dot product.

Answer (score 0):

You can stick with numpy

```
import numpy as np
import random


vals = []
num_vecs = 3
dimension = 4
for n in range(num_vecs):
    val = []
    for _ in range(dimension):
        val.append(random.random())
    vals.append(val)

# make into numpy array
vals = np.stack(vals)
print(vals.shape == (num_vecs, dimension))

# multiply every vector with every other using broadcastin
every_with_every_mult = vals[:, None] * vals[None, :]
print(every_with_every_mult.shape == (num_vecs, num_vecs, dimension))

# sum the final dimension
every_with_every_dot = np.sum(every_with_every_mult, axis=every_with_every_mult.ndim - 1)
print(every_with_every_dot.shape == (num_vecs, num_vecs))

# check it works
for i in range(num_vecs):
    for j in range(num_vecs):
        assert every_with_every_dot[i,j] == np.sum(vals[i]*vals[j])
```