# Zip two int lists with all possible sign combinations

Tags: python

Say I have two lists of ints:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,4]
```

And I want to end up with a list of tuples like this:

```
[(1,3),(2,4),(-1,-3),(-2,-4),(1,-3),(2,-4),(-1,3),(-2,4)]
```

That is, I'm zipping the nth element of `a` with the nth element of `b`, but using all possible positive/negative sign combinations. What's the most elegant way to do this?

A not elegant way would be to create two further lists like this

```
a_neg = [-n for n in a]
b_neg = [-n for n in b]
```

then zip `a` with `b`, `a_neg` with `b_neg`, `a` with `b_neg`, and `a_neg` with `b`, and combine the results. This works fine but is unsatisfying. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Do you need the list to be in that order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't try to be fancy with list comprehensions and just use a for loop

```
for idx, i in enumerate(a):
      c.extend([(i, b[idx]), (-i, b[idx]), (i, -b[idx]), (-i, -b[idx])])

>>> c
[(1, 3), (-1, 3), (1, -3), (-1, -3), (2, 4), (-2, 4), (2, -4), (-2, -4)]
```

Or using a zip

```
for x,y in zip(a,b):
     c.extend([(x,y), (-x, y), (x,-y), (-x, -y)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156963/python-positive-and-negative-number-list-possibilities) and just apply it across the zipped sequence, flattening the result into a single list.

```
from itertools import product

def sign_combinations(nums):
    return product(*((x, -x) for x in nums))

a = [1,2]
b = [3,4]
print([c for t in zip(a, b) for c in sign_combinations(t)])
```